# How can i add an object, boolean and long value into an array in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I have this method

```
private fun checkRoomIdAndFindCinemaAndCheckIfRoomExists(paramRoomId: String?, paramCinemaId: String?, roomExists: Boolean?) : Array<Any> {

    val roomId = ValidationHandler.validateId(paramRoomId, "room id")

    val cinema = cinemaService.getCinemaById(paramCinemaId)

    val roomExists = roomRepository.existsByIdAndCinemaId(roomId, paramCinemaId!!.toLong())

    return arrayOf(roomId, cinema, roomExists)
}
```

What i want to do here is add `roomId` as Long , `cinema` as object and `roomExists` as boolean into an array, and return type should be the array. How can i do that?

Later i want to access these from another method.

Comment: The accepted answer here is ugly, not type safe (not for creation, not for method signature, not obvious what index is what, and only is type safe when casting which is asking for a runtime error), it is not maintainable, not idiomatic.  Please change the accepted answer to the suggestion to use a `Triple` or data class.

Comment: You asked an "X/Y question" where you ask a question that leads towards an answer, but you asked the wrong question.  You should ask "Is there a way to avoid using an `Array<Any>` to hold these three typed items so I can pass them around as a group?"   Because, please, for all that is good in the world, do not use `Array<Any>` ...

Comment: @JaysonMinard you are absolutely right, i am sorry for my bad question, and i read the the answer and i understand why use the method in the answer, thank you for reply

Comment: it is not a "bad question" it is just a "X/Y question" which is something we want to reach back behind to find out where you were coming from so we can help get the best answer for you!  Good luck with Kotlin!

Comment: Thats true, and you also made me think more after what i am doing when i am creating methods , return types and things to keep track of in runtime. I appreciate for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use idiomatic Kotlin code instead of what was suggested already. When you want to return multiple values from a function, you should utilize data functions or existing classes like `Pair` or `Triple` if sufficient. In this case, `Triple` helps you:

```
private fun checkRoomIdAndFindCinemaAndCheckIfRoomExists(
    paramRoomId: String?,
    paramCinemaId: String?,
    roomExists: Boolean?
): Triple<Long, Any, Boolean.Companion> {
    //TODO
    return Triple(roomId, cinema, roomExists)
}
```

The good thing is that you can be sure about the types and don't have to cast anything from an unsafe `Array<Any>`. Furthermore, data classes let you make use of destructuring as shown here:

```
val (roomId, cinema, roomExists) = 
    checkRoomIdAndFindCinemaAndCheckIfRoomExists("id1", "id2", true)
```

Comment: It's not a created but a standard library class. If it weren't, I'd still suggest to do so

Comment: Take a look at one of OP's comment: *this help me avoid rewriting same code in other methods*. So what if he needs 4 or 5 values?

Comment: Then you create a data class for holding 4 to 5 values

Comment: Great and keep on going

Comment: This is exactly why data classes exist, is for cases like that.  And if not, use Triple because at least it would be typed instead of an untyped array @forpas.  Data classes are little effort but pay off heavily in value, and ARE the intended use case for situations like this.  Why avoid the actual tool intended for the job with untyped arrays?

Comment: @JaysonMinard Because it is not unsafe to use the values returned by a function that I created and know exactly how it behaves.

Comment: @forpas, it is unsafe since it is not protected by the compiler.  You are using a statically typed language and you have good options to do the same in a typed and safe way.  You are choosing an option that no one else would want to see in their code base.  Imagine you start doing this across other functions, different arrays, different contents, you get the order wrong in one, you don't notice, the compiler doesn't notice, you get random runtime errors later...  Why are you using Kotlin and then subverting fundamental principals?  And then arguing against the idiomatic form of the language?

Comment: Worse, you are then spreading this model in a public forum to unsuspecting people who'll read it and take the advice.  We should not be giving non-idiomatic answers here in Stackoverflow.  We can tell people bad advice, but we shouldn't.

Comment: *You are choosing an option* no I'm not. I see a function returning `Array<Any>` which is **idiomatic Kotlin** and I propose a valid solution.

Comment: The OP asked for something that would NOT be the idiomatic way to do it in Kotlin, and you gave him an answer for how to do the non-idiomatic thing in Kotlin.  You did a good job answering his question.  You did not do a good job of pointing out that this would be dangerous, and not a good way to pass around a complex return object.  I'm done here, people will hopefully get the point from the comments.

Comment: Actually, the OP asked for a typed array with three types in it, not knowing it isn't possible with an array.  They were asking for a `Triple` without knowing it existed, which is what THIS answer gives, so it is a good answer on all fronts.

Comment: @s1m0nw1 i liked your answer. I have read the arguments about why is should not use `Array<Any>`, i agree with Jayson about the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method like this:

```
val array = checkRoomIdAndFindCinemaAndCheckIfRoomExists(paramRoomId, paramCinemaId, roomExists)
```

The `array`'s inferred type is `Array<Any>`. 
You can access the items of the array:

```
val roomId = array[0] as Long 
val cinema = array[1] as YourObjectClass
val roomExists = array[2] as Boolean
```

Comment: Unsafe what? And since when `Array<Any>` and `a as b` is not idiomatic Kotlin?

Comment: can you be sure that the first element is a Long? Or that the second is what you want it to be?

Comment: Please do not create untyped arrays to hold parameter values, use either `Pair`, `Triple` or a custom data class.  All of these were made specifically for cases such as this.  By design, you should NOT use `Array<Any>`.